# EWS Managed API: Cannot Retrieve Contacts, it always return 0

Tags: api, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, managed

Good day.

I am using EWS Managed Api 2.0 to get the Exchange 2013 Contacts in my .NET 4.0 Application.

I have a working exchange server binding. here is my code.

```
FolderId foldid = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts);

                ContactsFolder contactfolder = ContactsFolder.Bind(exservice, foldid);
                ItemView view = new ItemView(500);
                view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);

                // Request the items in the Contacts folder that have the properties that you selected.
                FindItemsResults<Item> contactItems = exservice.FindItems(foldid, view);

                // Display the list of contacts. (Note that there can be a large number of contacts in the Contacts folder.)
                foreach (Item item in contactItems)
                {
                    if (item is Contact)
                    {
                        Contact contact = item as Contact;

                    }
                }
```

But When i run the code, the contactItems returns 0. This is strange because we have contacts in Exchange 2013.  ( Itemcount = 0, TotalCount = 0)

[EWS Managed API Contact is 0 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTMd1.png)

How do i solve this? 
I have posted this question into the Microsoft Tech Problem but no one replied yet.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you specify the Mailbox you want to access in the following line eg change

```
FolderId foldid = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts);
```

to

```
FolderId foldid = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts,"Mailbox@domain.com");
```

Most likely what is happening is your not accessing the Mailbox your expecting to, you can also do some testing with the ewseditor https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/

Cheers
Glen